# Scrapy how to loop extract data from different div class

Tags: scrapy

How do I extract data under different div class? I can only get it with span.field-content but not with div

```
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    <div class="views-field views-field-acronym">
      <span class="field-content">15CBOOKTRADE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="views-field views-field-title">
      <span class="field-content">The 15th-century Book Trade: An Evidence-based Assessment and Visualization of the Distribution, Sale, and Reception of Books in the Renaissance</span> 
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-field views-field-acronym">       
      <span class="field-content">2D-CHEM</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="views-field views-field-title">
      <span class="field-content">Two-Dimensional Chemistry towards New Graphene Derivatives</span>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

body = '''
     <div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    <div class="views-field views-field-acronym">
      <span class="field-content">15CBOOKTRADE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="views-field views-field-title">
      <span class="field-content">The 15th-century Book Trade: An Evidence-based Assessment and Visualization of the Distribution, Sale, and Reception of Books in the Renaissance</span> 
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-field views-field-acronym">       
      <span class="field-content">2D-CHEM</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="views-field views-field-title">
      <span class="field-content">Two-Dimensional Chemistry towards New Graphene Derivatives</span>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
    '''

for n in Selector(text=body).xpath('//span[@class="field-content"]/text()'):
    print(n.get())
```

Output

```
15CBOOKTRADE
The 15th-century Book Trade: An Evidence-based Assessment and Visualization of the Distribution, Sale, and Reception of Books in the Renaissance
2D-CHEM
Two-Dimensional Chemistry towards New Graphene Derivatives
```

Comment: is it necessary to insert the html body into the coding?

Comment: nop, I just showed it for the question section. actually we are using the page response here.

Comment: my result will be in one array right? cant be like the example? {'text': u'\u201cBut better to get hurt by the truth than comforted with a lie.\u201d', 'tags': [u'life'], 'author': u'Khaled Hosseini'} {'text': u'\u201cYou never really understand a person until you consider things from his point of view.\u201d', 'tags': [u'better-life-empathy'], 'author': u'Harper Lee'} {'text': u'\u201cI am good, but not an angel. I do sin, but I am not the devil. I am just a small girl in a big world trying to find someone to love.\u201d', 'tags': [u'attributed-no-source'], 'author': u'Marilyn Monroe'}

Comment: create a list and append iterated strings to this list, like `list .append(n.get())`

Comment: you will get the output like an array,
`['15CBOOKTRADE', 'The 15th-century Book Trade: An Evidence-based Assessment and Visualization of the Distribution, Sale, and Reception of Books in the Renaissance', '2D-CHEM', 'Two-Dimensional Chemistry towards New Graphene Derivatives']`